# How to manage private team shared libraries/packages in Python?

Tags: python

Our team would like to have some shared libraries/modules that we write to be available for several different projects. What is the best way to share these libraries between our projects? We use Bitbucket for source control, is there a way to install from a Bitbucket repository? Do we use pip? Do we need to create proper packages? We haven't created packages before, only done a few `pip install xyz`.

These would be for internal use only. We do not want to make our code available publicly.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [devpi](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/). It is a *powerful PyPI-compatible server*. You can [setup](http://doc.devpi.net/latest/quickstart-server.html) your own private server that works just like PyPI.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepare a private repository and use that via this way:

First install `pypiserver`: `pip install pypiserver`

Then create a directory: `mkdir ~/packages`
Now run `pypi` server in background: `pypi-server -p 8080 ~/packages &`

Now you can use it via these ways:

**1.**
`pip install  --extra-index-url http://localhost:8080/simple/ <your package name>`

**2.**
open pip config file (`~/.pip/pip.conf`) and add below config:

`[global]
extra-index-url = http://localhost:8080/simple/`

**3.**
or add `PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL` variable in your `bashrc`:
`export PIP_EXTRA_INDEX_URL=http://localhost:8080/simple/`

For more information check here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver/

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you should create proper (versioned) packages and upload them to private (or not) pypi server. Then just

```
pip install xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install with pip directly from a repository. See the docs on [VCS support](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support).

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in another answer, you can install from a repo. Also maybe look into [editable mode](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#editable-installs) if it's a small module and you are not building distributions (not using version numbers).