# Python pip package for organization

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am new on building Python package

I am going through this [tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) to build my first package.

I have a question of how to build the package that can be used by anyone in my organization. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48259271/pip-install-python-package-for-current-user), I can understand package can be written at user level.

My package has to be written for the organization. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=private+%22pypi%22+server+%22stackoverflow%22+site:stackoverflow.com&hl=en&pws=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjNvtbj2ujfAhUkh6YKHTWNAlIQrQIoBDAAegQIChAM&biw=1590&bih=689

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to manage private team shared libraries/packages in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665699/how-to-manage-private-team-shared-libraries-packages-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want people outside of your organization to see and use the package, you can use a private github repository to host the package, instead of uploading it to [pypi.org](https://pypi.org).

Make the [setup.py](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#creating-setup-py) file, and put your package on github (if you haven't done so already).

You can then use `pip install git+https://github.com/your-organization/your-repository.git` to install the package. (You *do* need to have pip and git installed)

Answer (score 1):

You can self hosted python package index use something like [pypiserver](https://github.com/pypiserver/pypiserver). Make it private that can be accessed only by your own organization.